# Hook directx dll without dll replacement in python

Tags: python-3.x, directx

I wonder is there a way to trace what functions and what args are called by a specific process from d3d9.dll without changing anything?

How hard is it to write my own script on Python for tracing calls to functions in DLL from game on DirectX?

I would like to view function and arguments that are called with New World MMORPG. In theory if can parse this without changing anything, than i will be able to get positions of all objects in front of me. Another object is to use Computer Vision.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/727-win-guide-to-hooking-windows-apis-with-python
Either way, you have to inject yourself into the game in order to hook its function, do this in c/c++ will be a lot easier using detours

Comment: Question edited